# PlayWright Save token for later use

Tags: playwright-typescript

For API-tests I have to get a token first.
Getting a token works with the following code:
```
test('Get accesstoken', async({request}) => {
const response = await request.post('https://...', {
headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
data: new URLSearchParams({
"client_id": "...",
"scope": "..",
"grant_type": "client_credentials",
"client_secret": ".."
}).toString()
});

````
    expect(response.status()).toBe(200);
    const resBody = JSON.parse(await response.text());
    const token = resBody.access_token;
    expect(resBody.token_type).toBe("Bearer")
    console.log(await token);
})

```
````

Now I have to save/store the token so that, when I execute the api in another test, I can use the saved token for authentication.

I found some examples on how to use the .env file but not on how to save varables there (or somewhere else).

Can someyone privibe me with some example code (typescript) on how to save a vaiable en the how to retrieve the value of the viaiable.

Thanks,
Andre

I tried saving the variable token in the .env-file but could not find code on how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should think of .env files as holding default declarations for your env variables. You cant dynamically set them from those files, but instead give them a default value. Perhaps this is an empty string, or something else.

Setting your token can be done directly in your API code if you wish. Something like:

```
expect(response.status()).toBe(200);    
const resBody = JSON.parse(await 
response.text());    
const token = resBody.access_token;
expect(resBody.token_type).toBe("Bearer");   
process.env.TOKEN = token;
console.log(await token);
```

Of course, my env variable name is just an example name, and you should change. Its as simple as that. Your .env file would give this TOKEN variable a default value, and it would set to your returned token in the code above.

Calling this in your tests can be added to your global setup, or project setup, or even a hook, so its always available!

Remember, you will need dotenv installed for this!

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: My .env file look like:
TOKEN = ''

When I execute the test I get no errors and the console shows the token but the .env file still shows an empty token: TOKEN = ''

Why is the value not saved in the file?

dotenv is installed.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what env variables are. They have a value only for the length of the running process in your case. As such, after the test run, they are set back to the value in the env file, which in your case is empty. This is why I mentioned they act kind of like a default value. They cant live outside of the running process, and as you are using API tokens, this is ideal. If you add this to a global or project setup, it will always be created and set for these tests meaning it will always have a value. Does that make sense? Happy to clarify more if you like!

Comment: Thanks for that. I indeed misunderstood what env variables are. I'm new to Playwright/typescript. The next step is to write an API-call which uses the stored value for authorisation and if stored well I shouldn't get a 401 :).

Comment: Awesome! If you could, can you accept the answer? This just really helps others who may have similar questions to find their answer! And always feel free to ask more questions, im here to help

Comment: I compeled the test to make use of the stored token. My code is :

 test('B. de Bruin', async({request}) => {
  const response = await request.post('https://...', {
   headers: {'Authorization': 'token ${process.env.TOKEN}'} , 
   data: klantData,
  });    

  expect(response.status()).toBe(200);
  const resBody = JSON.parse(await response.text());
  console.log(await resBody);
 });

The status is a 401 so the authorisation failed. I think I am still doing something wrong.
Is the line headers: {'Authorization': 'token ${process.env.TOKEN}'} correct?

Comment: Not quite. You need to escape it as you are using a literal. So replace that line with something like: headers: {'Authorization': ``token ${process.env.TOKEN}``} - not the use of backticks, not single or double quotes. As with this, you wont be escaping it, therefore it will be reading the whole line as a string! Lemme know if this helps and ill add it to my answer for accepting

Comment: @AndreHesdahl Stackoverflow formats backticks as code so my example doesn't show them exactly, but essentially just replace the quotes around the line token ${process.env.TOKEN} and replace them with ` (backticks). Does that help?

Comment: I tried that, but still got a 401. But in the code  ${process.env.TOKEN} is now in blue so it should be resolved.
But if I put a line of code in front:
console.log(await 'FROM.env: '+ process.env.TOKEN);
The console stays empy.
So the question is:
If I save a value to the .env in one test, can I read it in the next test?

Comment: Yes if the test that sets the .env variable is run beforehand. If you run things in parallel this wont work, so if its tests in the same block or file, you will need to run them sequentially

Comment: It should work but it doensn't.
When I put the line console.log(await 'FROM.env: '+ process.env.TOKEN); in de test where I save the token, I get a result. In the next test (in the same file) it is empty.

Is there another way to save the token in a file and retrieve it?

If I get the token in another way and put it right in I get a result of 200.

Comment: 2 things. If you manually add the token in, instead of using the env file, if you just hardcode it does it return 200? (That is to check if your token is actually valid). Second, are you running sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended solution is to use test projects to manage this sort of state. The process is as follows:

1. Create a setup test project that saves the API key to a file.
2. Create a functionality test project that loads the API key for tests. (This project will depend on the setup project.)
3. Create a teardown test project that deletes the file with the saved API key. (The setup project will mark this project as it's "teardown" in the config object.)

The process is detailed in the [Playwright docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-global-setup-teardown#option-1-project-dependencies).

Note: If you're running the same tests across multiple browsers, you'll have to decide if you want to (a) share one API key across all browsers or (b) use distinct API keys, saving them to separate files.